# Background color when click a div with OnClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I have some html code I wrote for cellular. I have problem only on galaxy s3 and it doesn't happen on other android's cellphones.

Here's some of the code:

```
<div id="more-time1" class="more-time" index="1" mode="NotAvailableToCall" onclick="toggle(this.getAttribute('index'), this.getAttribute('mode'))">
    some text
</div>

.more-time
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    color: dodgerblue;
    padding: 0.5% 0;
}

<script>
function toggle(index, mode)
{
}
</script>
```

When I click the element(div) with the event it add background color (like cyan) to the element. If I add selectors like active it still keeps appear when I click the element.
Any idea why does it happens? Any suggestions what can I do to fix it?
(It doesn't happen on S4, xperia Z3, lg g3)

Comment: are all the phone using same web browser?

Comment: @Woody it's not a web browser. It's a HtmlBox object which gets this html code (it runs in my application).